# What happens to spent perks if you cure yourself from being a vampire lord?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

As a Vampire Lord you gain access to a skill tree with some perks in it. What happens to points spent in these perks if you are cured? Are they refunded to be spent elsewhere or are they used up permanently?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once Vampire Lord/Werewolf perk points are used, they're set permanently. If you cure yourself and then get re-infected you'll retain all of the perks you originally unlocked. [As the wikia article describes it](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Vampire_Lord#Perks):

> Perk points allocated to the tree cannot be undone, although the vampirism can be cured through Falion's ritual. Requiring a filled Black Soul Gem, the affliction is reversed but all perks remain.

Also, it's not immediately clear what you mean by "to be spent elsewhere", but perk points for VL/Werewolf are drawn from their own pools. You can't spend them on the normal perk trees or on each other's trees.

Comment: Oh.. I guess my question should have been where do Vampire perks come from. I had assumed the same way all the others had been and I would have to forgo other skills if I got vampire lord ones (or werewolf now that I see they get a tree as well) and then not be able to use them any more if I was cured.

Comment: @James Well, when a mommy perk and a daddy perk love each other very much...